# Can I receive messages on my native app from Whatsapp Business API?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, whatwg-streams-api

So I am working on creating a native app for Whatsapp business users so that they can use this app to effectively chat with their contacts on Whatsapp. This mean that if another user messages a business user on Whatsapp then the business user is able to view the same message on a different app and respond to them from that app only.

Does Whatsapp API or any 3rd party like Twilio allow that to happen?

I tried using Twilio but it doesn't really work the way as mentioned above

Comment: In what way doesn't the Twilio API for WhatsApp allow for that? Or are you just looking for the [WhatsApp business app](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/)?

Comment: @philnash for instance I want to copy all my conversations on this native app and have conversations directly from this app rather than use whatsapp UI

Comment: Then yes, you could build this with Twilio. Indeed [Twilio Frontline](https://www.twilio.com/frontline) does this. The [Twilio Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations) should help you build this in a client side application